# WP задание инкремента для ID новой таблицы

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Такая задача, при активации плагина WP необходимо что бы в базе данных создавалась новая таблица (`fg_tournaments`) у которой бы для ячеек ID был назначен AUTO_INCREMENT и PRIMARY KEY...
Вот код для создания такой таблицы в плагине. [Идею взял отсюда](https://wp-kama.ru/function/dbdelta#example_34472)

```
function create_table()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'fg_tournaments';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();


            $sql ="CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `title` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
              `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
              `object_last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
                 `odject_published_up` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
            ) {$charset_collate};
            ALTER TABLE {$table_name}
            ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
            ALTER TABLE {$table_name}
            CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, add PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
            ";


            dbDelta($sql);
        }

        create_table();
```

Код создает таблицу в базе, но не назначает ни инкремента, ни первичного ключа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно его переписать?

Comment: Ну по идее Вы же можете прописать это в скобках после `CREATE TABLE`, что-то вроде `id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`. Не совсем пойму зачем там два раза `ALTER TABLE` и вот это в конце `CHANGE id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, add PRIMARY KEY (id);.`  `PRIMARY KEY (id)` так же можете установить в скобках перед `{$charset_collate}`

Comment: У меня минимум знания по mySQL, это тот запрос что сформировал редактор phpMyAdmin когда наклацать это из админки.  Вот оно чёт в php не отрабатывает. Может вообще там всё в один запрос при создании можно свернуть...

Comment: Ага, а то я думал может у Вас там какая-то задача хитрая) Попробуйте `"CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title varchar(128) NOT NULL, description text NOT NULL, object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, odject_published_up timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (id)) {$charset_collate}"`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это решило

Comment: MySQL? если так - он не позволяет выполнять несколько запросов за один раз, нужно делать запросы поочередно.